Why is 'Using keypad in guest virtual machine OpenVMS EDIT/EDT KEYPAD on a Linux host?' closed?
Using keypad in guest virtual machine OpenVMS EDIT/EDT KEYPAD on a Linux host?
Stack Overflow > Help center > Asking:


software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development


EDT has been the tool used by VMS programmer for creating source code files for over four decades. In what way is it not a legit question for SO?
How do I exit Vim? is the highest rated VIM question on SO, 5374. I found no comments indicating that it is not a good question for SO.

It's a bit of a grey area. I added the [edt] tag and reopened it, but you might get more answers on a more specific SE site like SuperUser

would you mind converting your images of text there into code blocks with language "none"? and making the title represent the question in the post body?

@Machavity - With the issues that exist with the question, while slightly within scope at Super User, it really wouldn’t be well received. The tone of this question by the author makes, me want to do zero favors for them, by listing those issues out if it were moved to a more appropriate community.

@SecurityHound 'this question' posted on meta or SO?

@CWHolemanII—The tone of this question is very direct and reads as if there can't possibly be any problems with the question you are asking about, despite several issues that do exist.


EDT has been the tool used by VMS programmer for creating source code file for over four decades. In what way is it not a legit question for SO?


The problem you report isn't anything to do with the EDT program, but in communicating with it via OpenVMS emulated in a virtual machine, which also entails emulating a VT100 terminal. The way that your emulation environment maps keys from your physical keyboard to VT100 commands has nothing to do with that program. Not only does this have nothing to do with EDT, it probably has nothing to do with (Open)VMS, either.

Most old, highly-upvoted questions about Vim would probably not be accepted today. On-topic questions about tools used by programmers are questions about tools used particularly by programmers, and particularly about using them for the task of programming. A text editor can be used by any computer user to edit any text file; it doesn't inherently have anything to do with programming.

Even if this were on topic, the question is quite poorly asked. We expect copied and pasted, properly formatted text, not screenshots of terminal contents; and it's way too much. If you want to convince us that "The help on VMS... does not identify useful info" (by the way, that's simply not correct English, and native speakers may struggle to understand what you meant), we don't need to see an image of all the information it is giving you. (Telling us what you tried is not about "deserving" an answer.)

Beyond formatting and content issues, the question is unclear: have you actually determined a need to "get the mapping for a PC keyboard"? How? For example, the help suggests that you should be able to use ctrl-E to increase indent level. What happens if you try actually just pressing that anyway, and how is that different? Keep in mind that depending on your setup, the issue might not just be with VT-100 terminal emulation, but with actually sending the key to the host OS (rather than the virtualization software).


In conclusion: please carefully rethink your question, and then try it on https://unix.stackexchange.com instead, after first checking existing Q&A to see if the underlying issues have been addressed already. Make sure that you have identified a concrete problem, and that you know where it is (e.g., pressing one keyboard combination sends something different to the program; or the keyboard combination you want to send to the program is captured by some intervening process - whether that's VirtualBox, xterm/GNOME Terminal/etc., or something else).

Just to be clear, vi/vim questions are generally on-topic. There's some grey area on some aspects of it (like installation), but questions about using it squarely fall under "programming tools". The question about exiting vi/vim is still on-topic. As such, questions about EDT are also on-topic.

@Machavity the answer provided there certainly doesn't read to me as if Vim questions are "generally" on topic. I would argue that most use of Vim is "from a non-programming aspect"; even when code is being edited, the fact that it's code is often completely incidental to the editing task. We take a lot of Visual Studio Code questions, but I don't think we'd take "how do I type an emoji in my string literal?" (as in, not using an escape sequence, or "is this supported by the programming language?", but literally how to make the symbol show up in the code editor window).

@KarlKnechtel depends on which group of "we"'s you ask. Bickering about which tool questions are on-topic is quite tiresome, that's for sure. And ultimately unrewarding because there is no consensus at all. Your point 2. does not make it so clear cut that the questions about VIM are actually off-topic; at most it would prove that the people who choose to make that tag their home have a strong opinion about it. But that can very well be only a handful of people, not representative enough to be called a "we".
